# How to calculate the expected value $E(X+X^2)$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable with pf $f(x)$.
The random variable $X$ takes on the values $2,3$ and $5$. With $f(2)=2/4$, $ f(3)=1/4$ and $f(5)=1/4$.
I know some of the laws of expected value like $E(x+a)=E(x)+a$,but I have never seen like this before. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Just write down the definition of expected value and compute it by hand.

Comment: thank you lulu for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the expected value of a random variable $Y$ with a finite number of possible outcomes is given by
$$
\mathbb{E} [X] = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i p_i
$$
where $y_i$ and $p_i$ are the value and the probability on a given outcome. Therefore in our case $Y=X+X^2$ and consequently the expected value is
$$
\mathbb{E} [X+X^2] =\sum_{i=1}^3 (x_i+x_i^2) p_i = (2+2^2)\frac{2}{4} + (3+3^2)\frac{1}{4}+(5+5^2)\frac{1}{4} = \frac{27}{2}.
$$

Comment: thank you so much, I am new to the topic so your answer helped a lot.